# Getting the last segment of path in case of using OR condition

Tags: scala, spray

I am new to spray framework, I have two routes that have similar functionality and only the last segment changes. I have combined it using the ‘|’ operator. How can I know which last segment was selected.

```
path("users" / Segment / "viewers_count") { userId =>

}

path("users" / Segment / "views_count") { userId =>

}
```

I have combined using

```
path("users" / Segment / ("viewers_count" |  "views_count")) { userId =>
      //here i want to know if viewers_count OR views_count
     // based on that I want to pass "viewers" OR "views" to a module
}
```

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple. You can extract it into a Map.

```
path("users" / Segment / Map("viewers_count" -> "viewers", "views_count" -> "views")) { (userId, selected) =>
      // here selected variable will contain viewers or views based on the path.
}
```

Comment: @user007  I've been using Spray/Akka for 3 years and never seen `Map` like this in routing. Could you please point to relevant piece of documentation for akka-http ?

Comment: @expert here is the [documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/path-directives/pathmatcher-dsl/#examples) from spray routing. atta-http, i don't know.